# Merge multiple columns into one and rename values based on column it came from

Tags: r, dataframe

Input data.frame looks like this:

```
col1 col2 col3
          1
     1   
1
     1
1
```

Which can be generated with this: (thanks to @Sotos)

```
d2 <- data.frame(col1 = c('', 1, '', 1, '', 1), 
                 col2 = c('', '', 1, '', 1, ''), 
                 col3 = c(1, '', '', '', '', ''), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

And desired output:

```
col1
3
2
1
2
1
```

How to merge columns like that? Empty cells are just empty, but solution with NA could be helpful as i can easily fill them.

Comment: Sorry for my previous wrong answer- What is the logic you want to implement? Should `col2` always be changed to 2? Are there no other values besides `NA` and `1`?

Comment: @dario Where do you see `NA`?

Comment: The empty values?

Comment: Exactly...empty. Not `NA`, so empty like `data.frame(col1 = c(1, '', 1, '', 1), col2 = c('', 1, '', 1, ''), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)`

Comment: Sorry for missing out details. The specific problem i have is five columns that can contain any kind of value. These values are in different columns, however, won't appera in the same row - e.g. first row will have only one value, second row also will have only one value etc.

Comment: Due to lack of a MRE I'm assuming they are numeric... What do you see?

Comment: @juststuck Please give a proper example that represents your full data frame. It is very different with only 2 columns and NAs from more than 2 columns with empty cells instead of NAs

Comment: Ok. I see. I give up. Sorry for not understanding your question. Was just trying to help you out. My bad :)

Comment: @dario no, don't give up. I am also just trying to put 1 + 1 together. It is more unclear from OP side

Comment: @Sotos is it more clear now?

Comment: Almost. Just clarify whether you have NAs or empty cells. And post a reproducible example. If they are empty then a reproducible example is: `d2 <- data.frame(col1 = c('', 1, '', 1, '', 1), col2 = c('', '', 1, '', 1, ''), col3 = c(1, '', '', '', '', ''), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)`

Comment: Is the goal to just sum across rows? This post has been edited so many times it is hard to follow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An approach using `data.table`

```
#library( data.table )
DT <- data.table( col1 = c(1,NA, 1, NA, 1),
                  col2 = c(NA, 1, NA, 1, NA) )
#    col1 col2
# 1:    1   NA
# 2:   NA    1
# 3:    1   NA
# 4:   NA    1
# 5:    1   NA

#update non-NA values to colnumbers
DT[, c("col1", "col2") := as.data.table( ifelse( is.na(DT), NA, col(DT) ) )]
#final output
DT[, .(col1 = fcoalesce( col1, col2 ) ) ][]
#    col1
# 1:    1
# 2:    2
# 3:    1
# 4:    2
# 5:    1
```

## update with provided sample data

```
d2 <- data.frame(col1 = c('', 1, '', 1, '', 1), 
                 col2 = c('', '', 1, '', 1, ''), 
                 col3 = c(1, '', '', '', '', ''), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

setDT(d2)
cols <- names(d2)
#update values to colunumbers
d2[, (cols) := as.data.table( ifelse( d2 == '', NA, col(d2) ) )]
#final output
d2[, .(col1 = fcoalesce( d2 ) ) ][]
#    col1
# 1:    3
# 2:    1
# 3:    2
# 4:    1
# 5:    2
# 6:    1
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `apply` and `which` like:

```
apply(d2==1, 1, which)
#[1] 3 1 2 1 2 1
```

or if needet with `unlist`

```
unlist(apply(d2==1, 1, which))
```

Using the data given by @Sotos.

```
d2 <- data.frame(col1 = c('', 1, '', 1, '', 1)
 , col2 = c('', '', 1, '', 1, '')
 , col3 = c(1, '', '', '', '', ''), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a `tidyverse` solution:

```
df <- df %>%
  replace(is.na(.), 0) %>%
  mutate(sum = rowSums(.[1:3]))
```

Answer (score 0):

A vectorized idea is to `stack`, replace with name index and update the original df, i.e.

```
d2_a <- subset(stack(d2[-1]), values == 1)
d2_a$values <- gsub('\\D+', '', d2_a$ind)
d2$col1[d2$col1 == ''] <- rev(d2_a$values)
```

which gives,

```
      col1 col2 col3
    1    3         1
    2    1          
    3    2    1     
    4    1          
    5    2    1     
    6    1
```